# MAUI Custom Control : XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Title", or mismatching type between value and property

Tags: .net, xaml, custom-controls, maui, bindableproperty

Am using MAUI application on .Net 6.
Created a custom control for activity indicator, and created bindable property for Running & title.

**CODE BEHIND**
``public partial class CustomProgressDialog : VerticalStackLayout { #region CTOR public CustomProgressDialog() { InitializeComponent(); } #endregion #region BINDABLE PROPERTY`

```
public BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(Title), returnType: typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(CustomProgressDialog), defaultValue:"Please wait...",
 defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
{
    var control = (CustomProgressDialog)bindable;
    control.TitleLabel.Text = newvalue as string;
});

public BindableProperty RunningProperty  = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(Running), returnType: typeof(bool), declaringType: typeof(CustomProgressDialog), defaultValue: false,

  defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
        var control = (CustomProgressDialog)bindable;
        control.Indicator.IsRunning = (bool)newvalue;
    });

#endregion
#region PROPERTY
public string Title
{      
    get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
    set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
}

public bool Running
{       
    get => (bool)GetValue(RunningProperty);
    set => SetValue(RunningProperty, value);
}
#endregion
```

`}`

`<VerticalStackLayout  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"                      x:Name="this"              x:Class="CustomControls.Controls.CustomProgressDialog">`
`<ActivityIndicator x:Name="Indicator" Grid.Row="1" IsRunning="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Running}" ZIndex="9999" WidthRequest="50" Color="#d12b8a" />`
`<Label              x:Name="TitleLabel"                   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Title}"             VerticalOptions="Center"              HorizontalOptions="Center" />`
`</VerticalStackLayout>`

`<custom:CustomProgressDialog Grid.Row="1" Running="{Binding IsBusy}" Title="{Binding Message}" ZIndex="9999"/>`

When a giving direct value instead of binding, then there is no error.
`<custom:CustomProgressDialog Grid.Row="1" Running="True" Title="Please wait..." ZIndex="9999"/>`
But when am using Binding then error.

XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Title", or mismatching type between value and property.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A bindable property can be created by declaring a public static readonly property of type BindableProperty.*  See [Create a bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-bindable-property)

you could change

```
public BindableProperty TitleProperty
```

to

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty
```

Hope it works for you.